# Messages getting added to deadletterqueue in AzureServiceBus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have multiple events defined in one service all these events are passed to another service through Azure Service Bus. But only one event is correctly consumed. All the other messages are directly added to the Dead Letter Queue. All the events derived from the same base class(including the one which is correctly consumed). I am getting the DeadLetterErrorReason as Maximum Delivery Count Exceeded.

The event just have a list of Guids.
The event which is consumed is having a list of string, an enum, and another string.
I couldn't find any issue with any of the properties. I'm new to Azure Service Bus

Comment: Do events that immediately go to the DLQ have TTL set? Is it all on the same subscription? Is "DLQ on filter evaluation expiration" set to true?

Comment: Yes it was going immediately and i found the issue. it was like my class was not having an empty constructor , so it was not getting desrialized. Thank You!. once i added empty constructor its getting consumed